# Scrollview inside Listview

Tags: android

I have a listview with mulitple rows, one of the rows must be a listview also with multiple rows, but only 2 of them need to be displayed, the rest displayed only on scrolling. i added a ScrollView with a LinearLayout inside the listview int he layout file and I'm adding the contents of the rows in the java file. The ScrollView doesn't seem to scroll well. Is there a better way of achieving this?
This is my layout file.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/listLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="1px"
    android:layout_height="1px"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >
</ListView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/listItem"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/formImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <include layout="@layout/vertical_list_item_title_area" />
</RelativeLayout>


    <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/childListLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<com.illumemobile.testapp.Classes.SCClasses.SCActivities.SCCustomActivities.SCCustomGallery
    android:id="@+id/horizontallistview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:spacing="33dip" />
```

Answer (score 3):

ScrollViews insides of ListViews are a VERY VERY bad idea. Not only is it confusing to the user, but the system has problems figuring out which View should get the touch events.

I would recommend rethinking about your layout.

Comment: but this is a requirement in several cases

Comment: How is this a VERY VERY bad idea if the code block above in the body of the question is scrollable while this entire page is scrollable as well? Should StackOverflow rethink its UI layout as well?

Comment: You are free to do whatever you want, I just know it's not a good idea. First off the scrollviews intercept the scroll events. Have you ever tried scolling using the mouse wheel to the bottom of a stack overflow post that has a bunch of long code snippets? It's not the best experience. In fact, stack automatically expands the heights of these blocks in their mobile apps to avoid this problem. Secondly, have you ever tried using narrator on Stack? It's nonexistent. In fact, the Windows Store launched with horizontal lists inside of a full page vertical scroll and quickly pivoted the design.

Comment: I get that it might not be the "best" UI experience, but there are cases where it's needed and even though it's a bad idea, this user (and myself) have found a case where it's a requirement. Answering with "rethink your layout" shouldn't be acceptable especially when we're programmers and we're supposed to find ways of solving problems.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend making a ScrollView, then inside the scroll view, making a LinearLayout.  Inside that LinearLayout you could have more LinearLayouts one or more items as children.  I think this would get close to what you're trying to do... I prefer using ScrollViews and LinearLayouts rather than trying to deal with ListViews.  LinearLayouts are a lot more dynamic than ListViews in my experience.
-Hope this helps